# Can't install OpenCV-3.4.0 on Raspbian Stretch (CMake error)

Tags: opencv, raspbian-wheezy

[Edit: It's Stretch, not Wheezy, sorry.]

I'm trying to build openCV on Raspberry Pi, following the instructions at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/ .

After installing all dependencies, I'm running:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- FP16 is not supported by C++ compiler
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   No package 'libdc1394' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Pylint (missing:  PYLINT_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:300 (message):
  No extra modules found in folder: /home/pi/opencv_contrib/modules

  Please provide path to 'opencv_contrib/modules' folder.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)


-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/src/convert.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/src/convert.fp16.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/src/convert.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/mathfuncs_core.sse2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/mathfuncs_core.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/mathfuncs_core.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/stat.sse4_2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/stat.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/test/test_intrin.fp16.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/corner.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/filter.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/imgproc/accum.sse2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/imgproc/accum.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/imgproc/accum.neon.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/objdetect/src/haar.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp
-- DNN_FACE_DETECTOR: Download: res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2018-02-26T01:35:42Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.14.21-v7+ armv7l
--     CMake:                       3.7.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:
--       requested:                 DETECT
--       disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++11:                       YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 6.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python2 python3 python_bindings_generator shape stitching superres ts video videoio videostab
--     Disabled:                    js world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.22.11)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.50.3)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.6.28)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.8)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (built-in)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.13)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.13)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.3)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.3)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The actual contents of /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log are:

```
Determining if the include file linux/videodev.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_9c20f/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/videodev.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c20f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_9c20f/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_9c20f/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file sys/videoio.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_19556/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/videoio.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_19556.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_19556/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_19556/fast] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is failing? I'm pretty new to OpenCV and CMake, so not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix it...

Comment: Possibly because you are trying to install on a 4+ year old doubly obsolete OS. You might have more "luck" with `OpenCV 3.0`, but I would ditch `Wheezy`

Comment: @Milliways: May I suggest posting that as an answer? :P I would imagine that the package dependencies in a 4+ year old unsupported OS are hardly reliable at this point.

Comment: Dammit! That's a typo. It's actually Raspbian Stretch! Sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting it to build contributed modules with the parameter

```
 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules
```

but the configure script is unable to find it:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:300 (message):
  No extra modules found in folder: /home/pi/opencv_contrib/modules

  Please provide path to 'opencv_contrib/modules' folder.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

Remove the parameter or add the contrib sources.

Comment: Yep! After taking a step back and thinking about it, the path was wrong. The correct CMAKE command was: cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv-3.4.0_contrib-3.3.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..